# Fancybox iframe not opening in IE

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have used below code at many places in my site

```
function display_modal_window_screen(url, height, width_param) {
    var is_update = 0;
    if (height == null || height == '') {
        height = 600;
    }
    width = 816;
    if (width_param) {
        width = width_param;
    }

    item = site_url + url;
    jQuery(".iframe").fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        width: width,
        href: item,
        //fitToView: false,
        beforeShow: function() {
            var file_url = $('.fancybox-iframe').attr('src').split(site_url);
            var file_arr = file_url[1].split('?');

            var window_height = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('html').height();
            var screen_height = $(window).height();
            if (window_height > 445 && window_height > 471 && window_height > 559 && window_height > 664) {
                this.minHeight = screen_height - 80;
            } else {
                this.minHeight = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('html').height();
            }
        },
        onUpdate: function() {
            var file_url = $('.fancybox-iframe').attr('src').split(site_url);
            var file_arr = file_url[1].split('?');
            var window_height = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('html').height();
            var screen_height = $(window).height();


            if (file_arr[0] == 'item_pre_screening.php' && sign_flag == false) {
                this.maxHeight = screen_height - 80;
                //$.fancybox.update();
                sign_flag = true;
            }

            if (file_arr[0] == 'sign_in.php' && (sign_flag == false || ($('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('#member_type_container').is(':visible') == true && is_update == 0))) {
                var window_height = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('html').height();
                if (window_height > screen_height) {
                    this.minHeight = screen_height - 70;
                } else {
                    this.minHeight = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('html').height();
                }
                sign_flag = true;
                if ($('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('#member_type_container').is(':visible') == true) {
                    is_update = 1;
                }
                $.fancybox.update();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then I use this html code

```
<a class="iframe" onclick="display_modal_window_screen('item_pre_screening.php?window=modal', 606,800);" href="<?php echo $site_url; ?>item_pre_screening.php">Item Pre-Screening</a>
```

I have used this html format to all places where I need to open fancybox on anchor tag. It is working fine in FF, Chrome and Safari but it is not working in IE.

Please help me out!

Comment: I see an stray `}` in your code. jslint it ;)

Comment: @JFK, I have edited it, That is not the issue actually. I expect answer from you only. I read many fancybox answers given by you in stackoverflow. Plz help.

Comment: this is the case where sharing a link to the page with the issue would help. I bet there is a js error that voids fancybox from working on IE

Comment: It is showing 'Invalid calling object' in jquery.min.js file. jquery.min.js holds version v1.7.1